# Line style Matching - Open CV?

Tags: python, opencv

I am new to the use of OpenCV. I intend to use it to match line styles in P&ID.

Line styles are something like this:

https://i0.wp.com/hardhatengineer.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/Pipeline-PID-Symbols.png?w=558&ssl=1

Novice here,How to approach it?

**Outcome:** The code should identify the start point and end point of line and name of it and highlight the line in particular color.

Effort so far:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('image.jpg',0)
img2 = img.copy()
template = cv2.imread('linepattern.jpg',0)
w, h = template.shape[::-1]

# All the 6 methods for comparison in a list
methods = ['cv2.TM_CCOEFF', 'cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED', 'cv2.TM_CCORR',
            'cv2.TM_CCORR_NORMED', 'cv2.TM_SQDIFF', 'cv2.TM_SQDIFF_NORMED']

for meth in methods:
    img = img2.copy()
    method = eval(meth)

    # Apply template Matching
    res = cv2.matchTemplate(img,template,method)
    min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(res)

    # If the method is TM_SQDIFF or TM_SQDIFF_NORMED, take minimum
    if method in [cv2.TM_SQDIFF, cv2.TM_SQDIFF_NORMED]:
        top_left = min_loc
    else:
        top_left = max_loc
    bottom_right = (top_left[0] + w, top_left[1] + h)

    cv2.rectangle(img,top_left, bottom_right, (0,0,255), 2)

    plt.subplot(121),plt.imshow(res,cmap = 'gray_r')
    plt.title('Matching Result'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
    plt.subplot(122),plt.imshow(img,cmap = 'gray_r')
    plt.title('Detected Point'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
    plt.suptitle(meth)

    plt.show()
```

Just using template matching tutorial to box the matching. But what I intend is trace the matching line pattern within the image in color.

Edit 2:
[image]

template:

[image]

Result:

[image]

[image]

Expected outcome:

Ok the above is expected outcome: The green highlight shows major pipeline and blue highlight overlaps dotted future expansion line(assuming it is dotted). Now, How to approach this problem? Forget bounding box, a highlight would do!

Comment: Got some sample inputs? | I probably wouldn't call this trivial. However, I'd suggest to remove that part of the question, as that is rather opinion base.

Comment: post some sample templates

Comment: @ Dan Masek, Removed Trivial. @ Janu777 Please see Edit 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break the problem into 3 parts:

1) **Highlighting the line style (template) in particular color:**

Steps:

- Find the location of template using template matching technique.
- Create a mask with white pixels in the template area and rest black pixels
- Highlight with a different line color in areas where the value drops below 255(assuming the line is in black color)
- Using the template,
  [image: Template]
- This is the output[image: Highlighting the line style]

2) **Finding the start and end points:**

Steps:

- Find the contour of the masked image containing just the line.
- Find extreme points of the contour (leftmost and rightmost)
- The points are shown [image: Start and End points]

3) **Finding the appropriate label of the detected line style:**

- Create a dictionary with template_ids and their corresponding labels
- With each template processed in the loop print out the labels

**Final Result:**

- For 5 templates this is the result I got. You can do the same for rest of the templates
  [image: Final Result]
- These are the output statements printed

> Label: Connecting Line; Starting_point: (24, 352); Ending_point: (169,
>   354)
>
> Label: Major Process; Starting_point: (18, 203); Ending_point: (163, 205)
>
> Label: Hydraulic; Starting_point: (22, 557); Ending_point: (168, 558)
>
> Label: Optical, Nuclear; Starting_point: (16, 64); Ending_point: (165, 69)
>
> Label: Jacketed or Double Containment; Starting_point: (23, 434); Ending_point: (167, 436)

Comment: Fantastic. Will it work for complicated P&IDs where lines overlap or criss cross?

Comment: For template matching to work you will need to have the exact templates. Meaning the template should properly match with the image. The image cannot be rotated or scaled. Have the templates cropped out from the image itself